# Autologin without any user interaction?

Tags: 16.04, login, password, login-screen, ubuntu-mate

I am attempting to create a web server with Ubuntu Mate 16.04LTS on my Odroid C2. I have tried configuring Ubuntu similar to this question [Enable/Disable Passwordless Login/Autologin Via GUI/Command Line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108955/enable-disable-passwordless-login-autologin-via-gui-command-line). However, while there is no longer a password prompt, I still am required to click the "login" button to login despite the absence of a password. How can I make it enter the desktop without any user intervention?

My rationale with this request is to eliminate the need for a keyboard/mouse. Since it is a single board computer, eliminating all peripherals would simplify things.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to get everything you need for a webserver to start on system startup without every having to login.

Comment: Thank you. I'll find out if Apache will start without having to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Apache, and other web server platforms, automatically start with the computer without logging in. Configuring automatic login is unnecessary for this situation.